# How to derive the surface gravity in terms of redshift factor in static spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon

I am following Carroll's book "Spacetime and Geometry" p. 245-247. I have the following expression for the surface gravity of a Killing horizon:
$$\kappa^2=-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla_{\mu}K_{\nu})(\nabla^{\mu}K^{\nu})$$
where $K^{\mu}$ is the timelike Killing vector that is orthogonal to the horizon.
If I have a static spacetime with the time translation Killing vector the four-velocity of a static particle is proportional to the Killing vector:
$$K^{\mu}=V(x)U^{\mu}$$
where V is the redshift factor.
Then, Carroll claims the following:
$$\kappa = \sqrt{(\nabla_{\mu}V)(\nabla^{\mu}V)}$$
How can I prove that?
I have attempted to substitute, use the Leibniz rule and cancel two terms by using the identity $U^{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}U_{\mu}=0$ (from conservation of the modulus of four-velocity), but I cannot go further.